# Spark Regexp: Split column based on date

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have a column, called "data", in my dataframe that looks like this:

`{"blah:"blah","blah":"blah"""10/7/17service`

I would like to separate this into three different columns that look like:

`col1: {"blah:"blah","blah":"blah"""
col2: 10/7/17
col3: service`

I have tried this approach:

`val separate = df.withColumn("col1", regexp_extract($"data", "(/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/)", 1)
.withColumn("col2",regexp_extract($"data", "(/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/)", 2))`

But this regex doesn't really get me through the door. I feel like I'm missing something about how the regex operator works in Spark. Any ideas?

Thanks so much!! :)

edit-rules for columns:

- col1: before the date value
- col2: date value
- col3: after the datevalue

Comment: What are the rules for the `col`s? `col1`: Match until it finds the last `"`, `col2`: Date, and `col3`: The rest of the string? Is this what you want https://regex101.com/r/TK2LrZ/1?

Comment: Yeah, that regex works! But how do I get that working within the spark scala code? I tried using that as the pattern instead and it didn't quite work out.

Comment: I'm not a scala expert, but could you try to use `regexp_extract($"data", "(.+\")(\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2})(.+)", 1)` and see if it works?

Comment: Woo! Okay that gets me the first column, not sure how to get the others working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, as you [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47560142/spark-regexp-split-column-based-on-date?noredirect=1#comment82086042_47560142) the rules are:

- `col1`: Match until it finds the last `"`
- `col2`: Match the date
- `col3`: The rest of the string

The regex you need is:

```
/(.+")(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})(.+)/
```

However, when you use it on the `regexp_extract()` function, you must escape the backslashes, so for each column, you'll use:

```
regexp_extract($"data", "(.+\")(\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2})(.+)", N)
```

Based on the code you wrote, try using this:

```
val separate = df.withColumn("col1", regexp_extract($"data", "(.+\")(\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2})(.+)", 1)).withColumn("col2",regexp_extract($"data", "(.+\")(\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2})(.+)", 1)).withColumn("col3",regexp_extract($"data", "(.+\")(\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2})(.+)", 3))
```

Comment: We posted at the same time! Thank you!! It's going :)

Comment: @mateaus, how do i do it so that it matches until the date for col1? because if there is no crazy json in front then doing this freaks out the columns.

Comment: As you're not matching until the `"` anymore, you must replace the `\"` in the regex with: `?`, so: `(.+?)` would be what will match the json.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @mateus for all your help!!

Was able to get it working just now with this command:

```
val fixed = df.withColumn("left", regexp_extract($"data", "(.+\")(\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2})(.+)", 1)).
  withColumn("middle", regexp_extract($"data", "(.+\")(\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2})(.+)", 2)).
  withColumn("right", regexp_extract($"data", "(.+\")(\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2})(.+)", 3))!
```