# How to read a pipe delimited text file in pyspark that contains escape character but no quotes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

Below is an example of my data in raw format and in a table:

`THis is a test|This is a \| test|"this is a \| test"`

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| THis is a test | This is a | test | "this is a | test" |

I am using the following script:

```
df = spark.read\
  .option("header", "false")\
  .option("escape", "\"")\
  .option("delimiter", "|")\
  .csv(file_dir)
```

However, the output looks like this:

```
df.show()
+--------------+-----------+-----+-----------------+
|           _c0|        _c1|  _c2|              _c3|
+--------------+-----------+-----+-----------------+
|THis is a test|This is a \| test|this is a \| test|
+--------------+-----------+-----+-----------------+
```

Essentially, I am trying to escape the delimiter if it is proceeded by a backslash regardless of quotes

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this you can write a new data reader that can handle this format natively.  Here's a good [youtube video explaining the components](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-eomYXVnvY&ab_channel=Databricks) you'd need.  Basically you'd create a new data source that new how to read files in this format.  A little overkill but hey you asked.

The alternative would be to treat the file as text and use some regex judo to wrestle the data into a format you liked. ([Similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47560142/spark-regexp-split-column-based-on-date))